# Clojure: passing a list of records to a Java object

Tags: groovy, clojure, jasper-reports

I am experimenting with Clojure. I was able to generate a report in JasperReports, but
it gives null values. The Java object in question is `JRBeanCollectionDataSource`.
I pass it a list of records, but somehow, the PDF contains only nulls.

Also, why am I not able to pass it `{}` as an empty `HashMap`? In Groovy, the `[:]`
syntax works OK.

```clj
(ns jasper.core
  (:import
   (net.sf.jasperreports.engine JasperCompileManager
                                JasperFillManager
                                JasperExportManager)
   (net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data JRBeanCollectionDataSource)))
(import 'java.util.HashMap)


(defrecord Car [id name price])

(def data [(->Car 1, "Audi", 52642)
           (->Car 2, "Mercedes", 57127)
           (->Car 3, "Skoda", 9000)
           (->Car 4, "Volvo", 29000)
           (->Car 5, "Bentley", 350000)
           (->Car 6, "Citroen", 21000)
           (->Car 7, "Hummer", 41400)
           (->Car 8, "Volkswagen", 21600)])

(def xmlFile "resources/report.xml")
(def jrReport (JasperCompileManager/compileReport xmlFile))

;; (def params {})
(def params (HashMap.))

(def ds (JRBeanCollectionDataSource. data))
(println (.toString ds))

(def jrPrint (JasperFillManager/fillReport jrReport params ds))

(defn -main
  []
  (JasperExportManager/exportReportToPdfFile jrPrint "report.pdf"))
```

This is a rewrite of the following working Groovy solution:

```
@Grab(group='net.sf.jasperreports', module='jasperreports', version='6.17.0')

import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource
import groovy.transform.Immutable

@Immutable
class Car {
    Long id;
    String name;
    int price;
}

def data = [
    new Car(1L, 'Audi', 52642),
    new Car(2L, 'Mercedes', 57127),
    new Car(3L, 'Skoda', 9000),
    new Car(4L, 'Volvo', 29000),
    new Car(5L, 'Bentley', 350000),
    new Car(6L, 'Citroen', 21000),
    new Car(7L, 'Hummer', 41400),
    new Car(8L, 'Volkswagen', 21600),
]

def empty = []

def xmlFile = "report.xml"

def jrReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(xmlFile)
def ds = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(data)

def params = [:]
def jrPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jrReport, params, ds)

JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jrPrint, "report.pdf")
```

*Edit* For a fully working example, place the following file in the current working directory for Groovy, and resources directory for Clojure.

```xml
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE jasperReport PUBLIC "//JasperReports//DTD Report Design//EN"
        "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/dtds/jasperreport.dtd">

<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports
   http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd"
              whenNoDataType="NoDataSection"
              name="report" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">

    <field name="id" class="java.lang.Long"/>
    <field name="name"/>
    <field name="price" class="java.lang.Integer"/>

    <detail>
        <band height="15">

            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="50" height="15"/>

                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>

                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.Long">
                    <![CDATA[$F{id}]]>
                </textFieldExpression>
            </textField>

            <textField>
                <reportElement x="150" y="0" width="100" height="15" />

                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>

                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String">
                    <![CDATA[$F{name}]]>
                </textFieldExpression>
            </textField>

            <textField>
                <reportElement x="200" y="0" width="100" height="15" />
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>

                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.Integer">
                    <![CDATA[$F{price}]]>
                </textFieldExpression>
            </textField>

        </band>
    </detail>

    <noData>
        <band height="15">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="200" height="15"/>
                <box>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#CCCCCC"/>
                </box>
                <textElement />
                <text><![CDATA[The report has no data]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </noData>

</jasperReport>
```

Comment: Can say for sure without a fully reproducible example, but `{}` creates an instance of a `Map` that's immutable and that's not an instance of `HashMap`. Also, `[]` does not create an array - it creates an immutable vector which is an instance of `List`. Finally, `defrecord` creates something that differs from what `@Immutable class` gives you, probably in a way that's important here.

Comment: For a fully working example, one needs to use one XML file; I have added this file. 

If it were caused by type mismatches, I would expect the example to fail with an exception.

Comment: For me the exception is: `Execution error (UnsupportedOperationException) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset/setDatasourceParameterValue (JRFillDataset.java:1291)`.

Comment: @cfrick I get this exact exception, when I define params as `(def params {})`.  If I use `(def params (HashMap.))`, the compilation works OK.  Then the problem is with `(def ds (JRBeanCollectionDataSource. data))`; the data is for some reason not correctly processed, I get nulls in the final report.

Comment: As I see in docs `JRBeanCollectionDataSource` expects collection of JavaBeans. `@Immutable` creates a JavaBean (crucial are getters, see [here](https://docs.w3cub.com/groovy~3.0/groovy/transform/immutable)) while Clojure record is not a JB. [clj-bean](https://github.com/wjoel/clj-bean) might be helpful here.

Comment: @generateme You are right; the problem is the JavaBean spec. VS Code does not like the  `clj-bean`; but it works. Why don't you  write an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the hints from the comments, I was able to resolve the issue. The problem is that Clojure records do not implement the JavaBeans spec, while the `JRBeanCollectionDataSource` expects such beans.

With the `clj-bean` library, I was able to make it work.

```clj
(defbean Car
 [[Long id]
  [String name]
  [Integer price]])

(def data [(Car. 1 "Audi" 52642),
           (Car. 2 "Mercedes" 57127),
           (Car. 3 "Skoda" 9000),
           (Car. 4 "Volvo" 29000),
           (Car. 5 "Bentley" 350000),
           (Car. 6 "Citroen" 21000),
           (Car. 7 "Hummer" 41400),
           (Car. 8 "Volkswagen" 21600)])
```

Now the report contains data.